# Filter a list and requesting data via ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile, cordova

im new to javascript and phonegap and im sitting here the whole day and try to solve this problem.

I have a list and i want to filter some data. And before i filter it, i want to download some data from a server and add it to the list. ( the list is local and if someone uses the search function, new data should pop up too).

The idea is that i create the list with jquery and use the listviewbeforefilter-event to download the data from a server and add it to the list. Then jquery should filter the list.

It works fine when i search filter for 2 chars.

But this doesnt work as expected when i search for more than 2 chars.
I receive the correct data from the server and it will be added to my list but the there is no more filtering in my original list. So i see my original list + the loaded data.
Also the console.log("second") is shown first and then console.log("first). Somehow jquery/phonegap skips the .then part and then comes back to it.

I tried to put the 3 lines ($ul.html( content );$ul.listview( "refresh" );$ul.trigger( "updatelayout");) below the second console.log and then the filter of my local data works but the data from the server wont be shown.

I hope someone can help me with this weird problem.

Heres my code for the listviewbeforefilter-event:

```
 <html>
 <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
    <title>Listview Autocomplete - jQuery Mobile Demos</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
     <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>

 <script>
    $( document ).on( "pageinit", "#myPage", function() {
    $( "#autocomplete" ).on( "listviewbeforefilter", function ( e, data ) {
        // this is a second list which is a backup. It is needed because after each search the original list is flooded with old entries.
        var content = document.getElementById("autocomplete2").innerHTML;
        var requestdata = "";
        var $ul =  $( this );
            $input = $( data.input ),
            value = $input.val();
        //  ajax call returns cities with at least 3 characters
        if ( value && value.length > 2 ) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://gd.geobytes.com/AutoCompleteCity",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                crossDomain: true,
                data: {
                    q: $input.val()
                }
            })

            // The response is saved in html which i append to the original content
            .then( function ( response ) {
                var html = "";
                console.log("first");
                $.each( response, function ( i, val ) {
                    html += "<li>" + val + "</li>";
                });
                content = content + html;
                $ul.html( content );
                $ul.listview( "refresh" );
                $ul.trigger( "updatelayout");

            });
            console.log("second");

            }

        });
    });
 </script>
```

and that is the body with the list:

```
     </head>
     <body>
     <div data-role="page" id="myPage">

        <div data-role="header" data-theme="f">
            <h1>Listview </h1>
        </div><!-- /header -->

        <div data-role="content">

            <div class="content-primary">
            <ul id = "autocomplete" data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder="Search people..." data-filter-theme="d"data-theme="d" data-divider-theme="d">

            <li data-role="list-divider">A</li>
            <li><a href="index.html">Adam Kinkaid</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html">Alex Wickerham</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html">Avery Johnson</a></li>
        </ul>

            </div><!--/content-primary -->

        </div><!-- /content -->
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
           $(function(){
                $( "#autocomplete2" ).hide();
                });
               </script>
        <ul id = "autocomplete2" data-role="listview"  data-filter-theme="d"data-theme="d" data-divider-theme="d">

        <li data-role="list-divider">A</li>
        <li><a href="index.html">Adam Kinkaid</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html">Alex Wickerham</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html">Avery Johnson</a></li>

    </ul>


     </div><!-- /page -->

     </body>
     </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fixed the issue. I changed the code :

```
     content = content + html;
     $ul.html( content );
```

to

```
  $ul.append( html);
```

i made a custom filter and recognized that the .then was always called AFTER the filter began.
Thats really weird because this method listviewbeforefilter should do everything before the filtering begins. I guess its because the ajax takes so long and will be skipped but later coming back to the .then method when the response received. I thought maybe async:false would help, but nope.

So basically it filters my local data and hides the list which are not needed and than i append the received data to the list.